# React filter multiple JSON requests with hooks

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, cloudinary

I am trying to make a filter that combines multiple filters.
The user can choose e.g. "big/not-big" and "heavy/not-heavy"
Each filter loads a JSON-file. However, I'd like to combine those JSON results, lets say I want big and heavy, I want to show the results that appear both in heavy and big.

I think I somehow have to ..onClick={add json to main array} -> only keep duplicates -> return json containing only duplicates

```
const Filters = ({doorHook}) => {
  const { setMainDoorList, select, setSelect } = doorHook;
  }
  const handleSelectChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSelect(value);
    setMainDoorList(value);
  };
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Item active={select === "big"}>
        <RadioButton
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          value="main"
          checked={select === "big"}
          onChange={event => handleSelectChange(event)}
          />
        <RadioButtonLabel />
        <div>Big</div>
      </Item>
      <Item active={select === "heavy"}>
        <RadioButton
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          value="heavy"
          checked={select === "heavy"}
          onChange={event => handleSelectChange(event)}
          />
        <RadioButtonLabel />
        <div>Heavy</div>
      </Item>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export {Filters};
```

For each JSON I want to fetch, I use this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMainDoors = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        await getDoorsByProducer(mainDoorList).then(res => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            setMainDoors(res.data.resources);
          } else {
            // Handle error
            setMainDoors([]);
          }
        }) 
      } catch(err) {
        // TODO: Catch error
        setMainDoors([]);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }
    if (!mainDoorList) return;
    fetchMainDoors();
  }, [mainDoorList])
```

This is an example of the JSON:

```
{"resources":[
{"public_id":"swedoor_debussy/Classic_Debussy_NCS_S_4050"},{"public_id":"swedoor_debussy/Classic_Debussy_NCS_S_7000"} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloudinary and try to find duplication. you might want to use the pHase:
https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_identify_similar_images_using_phash